# On submit and o'clock not working together

Tags: javascript, onclick, submit

I have read previous posts on this and have tried to apply the onsubmit on my form element in HTML but still doesn't seem to work. I have it as follows:

```html
<form class="button" id="arrow" onsubmit='return hotelList()'>
  <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

and js:

```js
const hotelList = () => window.location.href = './ochome.html';
```

Any suggestions? Thank you

---

Full code:
New Question: my required field does not seem to be working, and the  sends me to the other page regardless....

```
enter code here 

<form action="/user-details.html" class='login'>
            <!-- is this GET or POST?? -->
            <label for="username" >Username</label><br>
            <input class="whitebox" type="text" id='username' required/>
            <label for="pass" id='pass'>Password</label><br>
             <input class="whitebox" type='password' id='passBox' required/>
            <input type="submit" id='arrow' value="> Submit">
          </form>
```

Comment: Sorry my HTML: <form class="button" id="arrow" onsubmit='return hotelList()'>
                <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
              </form>

Comment: try typing: <form class="button" id="arrow" onsubmit='hotelList()'> w/o return

Comment: maybe you want to redirect the user to ochome? if so you can remove the form tag and put a button wrapped by an a tag with href attribute

Comment: I did have the <a> with href but then it didn't seem to respect the required - will try again, thank you

Comment: that happen when you missed the action attribute on form. you should use form and submit  button only when you need to send data to a server (let's say a contact form).

Comment: Exactly, so now the required doesn't work.... no matter what it does go to the new page because of the <a> - thoughts?

Comment: But the action will send the data somewhere rather than redirecting me no? ok, so I was actually trying to link js to this and this is where I was failing even more as I wanted a message to come up if the user and pass did not meet the criteria.

Comment: <div class="login">
          <p>Username</p>
   
                <form action="user-details.html" method="POST">
                  <input class="whitebox" type="text" id='username' required/>
                </form>
                <p id='pass'>Password</p>
                <form action="user-details.html" method="POST">
                  <input class="whitebox" type='password' id='passBox' required/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <a href="./ochome.html">  
              <button class="button" id="arrow">Submit
              </button>
            </a>

Comment: const submit = document.getElementById('arrow');
const pass = document.getElementById('passBox');
const username = document.getElementById('username');


let isFilled = () => username.length >1;

let validPass = () => pass.length >7;

submit.onclick = () =>  {
    if(isFilled && validPass) {
        window.location.href = './ochome.html';
    }
    
};

Comment: can you post the entire code?

Comment: Just have :), thank you, (I am very new to this and have a project I want to deliver)

Comment: your code is very messy. have a look here --> https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp and keep trying! I'll post the answer below

Answer (score 0):

the form contains all the input you want to submit and the action is like: action="/file.js" and it has to be a file which handles the data

the code:

```
<form action="/user-details.html">
      <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
      <input class="whitebox" type="text" id='username' required/>
      <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
       <input class="whitebox" type='password' id='passBox' required/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: and then use label tags to give a name to inputs instead of <p>

Comment: thank you @fabriziogianni7, what about the js part? It believe it might also be messy and incomplete but any tips are appreciated

Comment: Submit and o'clock don't work together I figured, nonetheless, my required field still doesn't work and is goes to the next page regardless - I will update what I have now on HTML

Comment: try adding <!DOCTYPE html> at the beginning of the page

Comment: That is all there...<!DOCTYPE> and <html></html>